# Identifying current cursor type using ObjectiveC in OSX

Tags: objective-c, macos

I am writing an app in ObjectiveC for Mac. I wanted to identify the current type of cursor(pointingHandCursor or arrowCursor etc.) that is shown in the display. How can I find it?

I know, [NSCursor currentSystemCursor] can be used to get the current cursor object. How can I find the cursor type using this NSCuror object?

Comment: This falls into the "What are you really trying to do?" category. If you are just wanting to save it so you may restore it later you can push/pop the current cursor. Or use the "currentSystemCursor" method you mentioned to save and later restore it (no advantage over push/pop thou).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.

Just like NSColor or UIColor (which have "redColor" and "blueColor" convenience methods that only set up the object -- and don't leave anything identifiable behind), you *cannot* get the name of the convenience method that set up your current NSCursor.

***UNLESS***....... you subclass NSCursor (e.g. SenthilCursor) and all the methods that come with it and then you yourself keep track of which cursor was last selected.

This would work only with your own app and not when the cursor is changed by other apps outside of your app.

Comment: Is it possible find the cursor type using C-language in a Mac app?

Comment: The only 64-bit compatible straight C functions for the cursor in MacOS that I know of are [hiding in Quartz Display Services](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/Quartz_Services_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001070-CH202-BAJCGFCI), and none of them mention the cursor name there either.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I will to try subclass-ing NSCursor.